UIViewRepresentable unnecessarily recreates view when its SwiftUI offset property changes causing performance issues
I'm coding a wrap-around carousel component for SwiftUI (minimum target iOS 15.0) with zoom and pan functionality.
The idea is the following:

There are two buffers: one that contains three images and is shown on screen, called onScreenBuffer, and one that's used to prepare updates for it, of the same size, called offScreenBuffer.
Users can perform drag gestures on the component. When drag ends, if the finger dragged long enough horizontally, offScreenBuffer gets recreated from scratch, "centered" on the new index.
Before buffers are swapped, a value that represents the index of the next image in the onScreenBuffer, called offsetImageSelector gets updated according to the drag direction.
When the animation ended and the component is idle, under the hood offScreenBuffer is copied onto onScreenBuffer and offsetImageSelector is reset to 0.

I'll include an image to visually represent the concept I'm expressing, starting from when the component first renders.

Now, for the sake of discussing what's going to happen, let's consider the following scenario:
Right Swipe (dragOffset > 0)
When the user drags long enough towards right the component is supposed to show the previous image than the one that's currently being shown. This is how it's achieved:

Update offScreenBuffer and offsetImageSelector (the latter, to trigger the swipe animation). Note that the offset for the carousel component is (dragOffset - containerWidth)*(1-offsetImageSelector), therefore while idle the presented image is onScreenBuffer[1]; a right swipe exposes onScreenBuffer[0] and a left swipe exposes onScreenBuffer[2].



The change in offsetImageSelector from 0 to 1 causes the animation of the following transition:



When animation @2 is completed, offScreenBuffer overwrites onScreenBuffer and offsetImageSelector is reset to 0, as shown here.


The Code
I'm omitting the left swipe since it's perfectly symmetrical. Here's my current implementation (MRE, the actual component is definitely more complex than that):
PinchableViewRepresentable.swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct PinchableViewRepresentable<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    var id: String
    private var content: () -> Content
    internal var minimumZoomScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    internal var maximumZoomScale: CGFloat = 20.0
    internal var bouncesZoom: Bool = true
    internal var resetZoomOnDoubleTap: Bool = true
    internal var onDoubleTap: (() -> Void)?
    internal var onSingleTap: (() -> Void)?
        
    @Binding internal var zoomObserver: CGFloat
    @Binding internal var scrollObserver: CGPoint
        
    init(
        id: String = UUID().uuidString,
        zoomObserver: Binding<CGFloat> = .constant(0),
        scrollObserver: Binding<CGPoint> = .constant(.zero),
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content,
        onSingleTap: (()->Void)? = nil,
        onDoubleTap: (()->Void)? = nil
    ) {
        self._zoomObserver = zoomObserver
        self._scrollObserver = scrollObserver
        self.content = content
        self.onSingleTap = onSingleTap
        self.onDoubleTap = onDoubleTap
        self.id = id
        print("PinchableViewRepresentable#\(id) init")
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        // set up the UIScrollView
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator  // for viewForZooming(in:)
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = self.maximumZoomScale
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = self.bouncesZoom

        // create a UIHostingController to hold our SwiftUI content
        let hostedView = context.coordinator.hostingController.view!
        hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        hostedView.frame = scrollView.bounds
        scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)
        hostedView.backgroundColor = .clear
        context.coordinator.scrollView = scrollView
        
        context.coordinator.onSingleTap = self.onSingleTap
        context.coordinator.onDoubleTap = self.onDoubleTap
        
        if self.resetZoomOnDoubleTap {
            let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                target: context.coordinator,
                action: #selector(context.coordinator.handleDoubleTap(_:))
            )
            
            doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
            scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
            context.coordinator.doubleTapRecognizer = doubleTapGestureRecognizer
            
            let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                target: context.coordinator,
                action: #selector(context.coordinator.handleSingleTap(_:))
            )
            
            singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
            context.coordinator.singleTapRecognizer = singleTapGestureRecognizer
            
            singleTapGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
        }
        
        context.coordinator.setZoomObserver(self._zoomObserver)
        context.coordinator.setScrollObserver(self._scrollObserver)
        
        return scrollView
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(hostingController: UIHostingController(rootView: self.content()))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        
        print("PinchableViewRepresentable#\(id) updateUIView")
        context.coordinator.scrollView = uiView
        context.coordinator.hostingController.rootView = self.content()
        
        let updateTask = {
            context.coordinator.setZoomObserver(self._zoomObserver)
            context.coordinator.setScrollObserver(self._scrollObserver)
            
         //   uiView.zoomScale = self.zoomObserver
         //   uiView.contentOffset = self.scrollObserver
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            updateTask()
        }

        assert(context.coordinator.hostingController.view.superview == uiView)
    }

    // MARK: - Coordinator
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>
        var scrollView: UIScrollView? = nil
        var onDoubleTap: (() -> Void)? = nil
        var onSingleTap: (() -> Void)? = nil
        
        @Binding var zoomObserver: CGFloat
        @Binding var scrollObserver: CGPoint
        
        var doubleTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!
        var singleTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!
        var lastFiredZoom: Date = .distantPast
        var lastFiredScroll: Date = .distantPast
        
        init(
            hostingController: UIHostingController<Content>,
            onSingleTap: (() -> Void)? = nil,
            onDoubleTap: (() -> Void)? = nil,
            zoomObserver: Binding<CGFloat> = .constant(.zero),
            scrollObserver: Binding<CGPoint> = .constant(.zero)
        ) {
            self.hostingController = hostingController
            self.onSingleTap = onSingleTap
            self.onDoubleTap = onDoubleTap
            self._zoomObserver = zoomObserver
            self._scrollObserver = scrollObserver
        }

        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
          return hostingController.view
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if #unavailable(iOS 16.0) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    if self.lastFiredZoom.distance(to: Date.now) > 1.0/90.0 {
                        zoomObserver = scrollView.zoomScale
                        self.lastFiredZoom = Date.now
                    }
                }
            } else {
                zoomObserver = scrollView.zoomScale
            }
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
            zoomObserver = scrollView.zoomScale
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            scrollObserver = scrollView.contentOffset
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if #unavailable(iOS 16.0) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    if self.lastFiredScroll.distance(to: Date.now) > 1.0/90.0 {
                        self.scrollObserver = scrollView.contentOffset
                        self.lastFiredScroll = Date.now
                    }
                }
            } else {
                self.scrollObserver = scrollView.contentOffset
            }
        }
        
        func setZoomObserver(_ zoomObserver: Binding<CGFloat>) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self._zoomObserver = zoomObserver
            }
        }
        
        func setScrollObserver(_ scrollObserver: Binding<CGPoint>) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self._scrollObserver = scrollObserver
            }
        }
        
        @objc dynamic func handleDoubleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            guard let scrollView = self.scrollView else { return }
            
            let zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
            
            switch sender.state {
                case .ended:
                    scrollView.setZoomScale(1.0, animated: true)
                    
                if zoomScale == 1.0 {
                    let imageView = scrollView.subviews.first!
                    let point = doubleTapRecognizer.location(in: imageView)
                    
                    let scrollSize = scrollView.frame.size
                    let size = CGSize(width: scrollSize.width / (scrollView.maximumZoomScale/2.0),
                                      height: scrollSize.height / (scrollView.maximumZoomScale/2.0))
                    let origin = CGPoint(x: point.x - size.width / 2,
                                         y: point.y - size.height / 2)
                    scrollView.zoom(to:CGRect(origin: origin, size: size), animated: true)
                    
                    
                    self.onDoubleTap?()
                }
                
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
        
        @objc dynamic func handleSingleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            guard let onSingleTap = self.onSingleTap else { return }
            onSingleTap()
        }
        
    }
}

CGSize + sizeThatFits.swift
import CoreGraphics

extension CGSize {
    static func sizeThatFits(containerSize: CGSize, containedAR: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        if containedAR.isZero || containedAR.isNaN || containedAR.isInfinite {
            #if DEBUG
                print("Unexpected input parameter `containedAR` value: \(containedAR)")
            #endif
            return .zero
        } else {
            var proposedSize: CGSize = .zero
            
            if containedAR > containerSize.width / containerSize.height {
                proposedSize.width = containerSize.width
                proposedSize.height = containerSize.width / containedAR
            } else {
                proposedSize.height = containerSize.height
                proposedSize.width = containerSize.height * containedAR
            }
            
            #if DEBUG
            if proposedSize.width > containerSize.width || proposedSize.height > containerSize.height {
                print("Computed size \(proposedSize) unexpectedly exceeds container size \(containerSize)")
            }
            #endif
            
            return proposedSize
        }
    }
}

ZTronImageModel.swift:
import Foundation

class ZTronImageModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var imageID: String
    private var position: Int
    var id: String
    
    init(image: String, position: Int) {
        self.imageID = image
        self.position = position
        self.id = imageID
    }

    static func == (lhs: ZTronImageModel, rhs: ZTronImageModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(imageID)
    }
    
    func getName() -> String {
        return self.imageID
    }
    
    func getPosition() -> Int {
        return self.position
    }
    
    static var zero: ZTronImageModel = ZTronImageModel(
        image: "YadaYadaYada",
        position: 0
    )
}

ZTronCarouselModel.swift
import SwiftUI

class ZtronCarouselModel: ObservableObject {
    internal var onScreenBuffer: [BufferedZTronImageModel] = []
    private var offScreenBuffer: [BufferedZTronImageModel] = []
    internal var currentImage: Int = 0
    @Published internal var offsetImageSelector: Int = 0
        
    //MARK: - Images set
    @Published internal var imagesIDs: [ZTronImageModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            guard imagesIDs.count > 0 else { return }
            self.makeBuffer(for: self.currentImage, buffer: &self.onScreenBuffer)
            self.makeBuffer(for: self.currentImage, buffer: &self.offScreenBuffer)
        }
    }
        
    init(){
        imagesIDs = [
            ZTronImageModel(image: "Police", position: 0),
            ZTronImageModel(image: "Shutter", position: 1),
            ZTronImageModel(image: "Depot", position: 2),
            ZTronImageModel(image: "Cakes", position: 3),
            ZTronImageModel(image: "Sign", position: 4)
        ]
    }
            
    //MARK: - ViewController
    internal func makeBuffer(for centralIdx: Int, buffer: inout [BufferedZTronImageModel])  {
        precondition(centralIdx >= 0 && centralIdx < self.imagesIDs.count)
        var tempBuffer: [BufferedZTronImageModel] = []
        
        if tempBuffer.count < 3 {
            tempBuffer = [BufferedZTronImageModel].init(repeating: .zero, count: 3)
        }
        
        for i in -1...1 {
            let next = (centralIdx + i + imagesIDs.count) % imagesIDs.count
            tempBuffer[i+1] = BufferedZTronImageModel(imageModel: imagesIDs[next], position: i+1)
        }
        
        buffer = tempBuffer
    }
    
    func prepareForNext(forward: Bool = true) {
        let nextIdx = forward ? (currentImage+1)%imagesIDs.count : (currentImage-1+imagesIDs.count) % imagesIDs.count
        
        self.offsetImageSelector += forward ? -1 : 1
                
        assert(nextIdx >= 0 && nextIdx <= imagesIDs.count)
        
        self.makeBuffer(for: nextIdx, buffer: &self.offScreenBuffer)
        currentImage = nextIdx
        
    }
    
    func swapOnscreenBuffer() {
        self.onScreenBuffer = Array(self.offScreenBuffer)
        self.offsetImageSelector = 0
    }
    
    internal struct BufferedZTronImageModel: Identifiable {
        var imageModel: ZTronImageModel
        var position: Int
        var id: String
        
        init(imageModel: ZTronImageModel, position: Int) {
            self.imageModel = imageModel
            self.position = position
            //self.id = "\(imageModel.id)\(position)"
            self.id = imageModel.id
        }
        
        public static let zero = BufferedZTronImageModel(imageModel: .zero, position: .zero)
    }
}

ZtronCarouselViewAlt.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ZTronCarouselViewAlt: View {
    @StateObject private var carouselModel = ZtronCarouselModel()
    @State private var dragOffset: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let expectedImageVFraction = CGSize.sizeThatFits(containerSize: geo.size, containedAR: 16.0/9.0).height / geo.size.height
            let needsVerticalLayout = expectedImageVFraction <= 0.75

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(carouselModel.onScreenBuffer, id: \.id) { bufferedImage in
                            PinchableViewRepresentable(id: bufferedImage.imageModel.getName()) {
                                Image(bufferedImage.imageModel.getName())
                                    .resizable()
                            }
                            .frame(width: geo.size.width + geo.safeAreaInsets.leading + geo.safeAreaInsets.trailing, alignment: .leading)
                            .overlay {
                                Text("\(carouselModel.offsetImageSelector)")
                                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .zIndex(1.0)
                    .offset(
                        x: (dragOffset - (geo.size.width + geo.safeAreaInsets.leading + geo.safeAreaInsets.trailing)) * CGFloat((1 - carouselModel.offsetImageSelector))
                    )
                    .aspectRatio(16.0/9.0, contentMode: .fit)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20)
                            .onChanged { value in
                                if carouselModel.offsetImageSelector == 0 {
                                    dragOffset = value.translation.width
                                } else {
                                    dragOffset = 0
                                }
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                onDragEnded(galleryWidth: geo.size.width + geo.safeAreaInsets.leading + geo.safeAreaInsets.trailing)
                            }
                    )
                    .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width + geo.safeAreaInsets.leading + geo.safeAreaInsets.trailing, alignment: .leading)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .clipped()
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: [.leading, .trailing])
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: needsVerticalLayout)
            }
        }
    }

    private func onDragEnded(galleryWidth: CGFloat) {
        let swipePercentage = abs(dragOffset) / galleryWidth

        if swipePercentage > 0.2 {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.25)) {
                carouselModel.prepareForNext(forward: dragOffset < 0)
                dragOffset = 0
            }
            

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                carouselModel.swapOnscreenBuffer()
            }

        } else {
            print("\(#function) path 1.2")
            withAnimation {
                self.dragOffset = 0
            }
        }
    }
}

The Issue
As I recorded here, the PinchableViewRepresentable component gets recreated (.init() invoked) and updated updateUIView() multiple times during drag gesture, and the same thing happens during interface orientation changes, causing bad animations (tested on real device iPhone 6S with iOS 15.8, and iPhone 15 Pro simulator).
Using the SwiftUI instrument it looks like the component re-renders because Binding<CGFloat> and Binding<CGPoint> changed, even though in this MRE default constant values are used for zoomObserver and scrollObserver.
Using Self._printChanges() I only get the following:
ZTronCarouselViewAlt: @self, @identity, _carouselModel, _dragOffset changed.
ZTronCarouselViewAlt: _dragOffset changed.
[...]
ZTronCarouselViewAlt: _dragOffset changed.
ZTronCarouselViewAlt: _carouselModel changed.

So during first render @identity changes and after that, only _dragOffset changes when the redundant updates happen.
The actual PinchableViewRepresentable content is way more complex than that as well, and it has an overlay that depends on zoomObserver and scrollObserver, so the problem gets pretty bad, mostly during rotations.
For the sake of testing it yourself, you can add to your assets folder any set of 16:9 images named "Police", "Shutter", "Depot", "Cakes", "Sign" (with that exact case).
EDIT
The issue persists if I reduce PinchableViewRepresentable to this:
struct PinchableViewRepresentable<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    private var content: Content
        
    init(
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.content = content()
        print("PinchableViewRepresentable#\(#function)")
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        // set up the UIScrollView
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 20.0
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
        
        // create a UIHostingController to hold our SwiftUI content
        let hostedView = UIHostingController(rootView: content).view!
        hostedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        hostedView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        hostedView.frame = scrollView.bounds
        scrollView.addSubview(hostedView)
        hostedView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        
        print("PinchableViewRepresentable#\(#function)")
    }
}


all the DispatchQueue calls look suspect to me since View structs have no lifetime like objects do

Those DispatchQueue calls were there as temporary fixes to “Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior” warnings (leftovers from the original code). I'll check if that was it as soon as possible.

@malhal: I tried removing every single DispatchQueue call and reintroducing them one by one. Even with no call to it I keep getting tons of calls to .init() for the PinchableViewRepresentables when _dragOffset changes, and 4 calls to .init() + 4 calls to updateUIView() as soon as _carouselModel changes. So I guess it wasn't it.
I also tried removing zoomObserver and scrollObserver and all their usages, it still didn't solve.

It would be better to fix the “modifying state during update” issue first then you wouldn’t even need the dispatches. In updateUIView, check if the value has changed before doing anything.

@malhal: I believe that “modifying state during update” stems from the fact that UIKit and SwiftUI have different view update policies: the former updates when constraints changed and the latter when intrinsicContentSize changed. If that's the case there's not much I can do other than dispatching on the main queue. Though I verified that DispatchQueue.main.async calls aren't the source of the redundant .init() calls since removing all of them doesn't fix the issue.

I don't think so. Try fixing your PinchableViewRepresentable init so that update isn't called so often, eg remove the id. Then in update disable your callbacks while you are updating the uiview.

@malhal: I tried removing all the parameters from .init() except content, which is absolutely necessary. and now I get three calls to .init() and three calls to .updateUIView() every time ._dragOffset changes. So I'd say it wasn't it.

You need to change content to self.content = content()

@malhal: I tried that already as I just came across this post. Unfortunately it didn't fix.

Keep trying you'll eventually get there without the need for DispatchQueue

@malhal: I removed just about everything I could from PinchableViewRepresentable and the issue is still there. I think it's now safe to say that it is not the source of the issue. See my edit.

Try UIViewControllerRepresentable

@malhal: I'm currently trying that as well. I'm still getting similar results so at this point I'm just assuming it's to be expected to have .init() called multiple times and will design it with that in mind.

move the logic from ZtronCarouselModel into the Coordinator. Move the imagesIDs to @State

@malhal: Unfortunately that'd defeat the point of making PinchableViewRepresentable a component. I thought of it as a building block to use in different scenarios inside my apps, while moving code from ZtronCarouselModel to PinchableViewRepresentable.Coordinator would tie it to that specific use case. At that point I might as well code an UICollectionViewController in UIKit and bridge that using UIViewControllerRepresentable.
